# How to get the client's IP after receiving a UDP packet with recvfrom() in C?

Tags: c, udp

Is there a way, as the server, to get the client's IP address as a string after receiving a message from the client with `recvfrom()`? I would assume it is in the `sockaddr_in` struct, but I don't know how to access it. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The IP address is indeed stored in the `struct sockaddr` or `struct sockaddr_in` whose address was passed to `recvfrom`, and (assuming the structure is named "`sender`") it can be converted to a string with:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

char* ipString = inet_ntoa(sender.sin_addr);
```